# How to read from socket without blocking

Tags: asynchronous, socket.io, julia

I ran into a problem when dealing with the server, sending me initial "greetings header" (smtp server):

I need to read this header before send any commands and receive any answers from the server, but i dont know, how to do this, because Julia seems to lack any possibility to readi from IO stream without blocking: "read" command and its analogues does not have any NB-options, nb_available always is 0 though i know exactly that server send me header and my read buffer cant be empty (and "read" command issued right after "nb_available" give me data immediately, without blocking).

```
julia> s=connect("smtp.mail.ru",25)
TCPSocket(RawFD(18) open, 0 bytes waiting)

julia> nb_available(s)
0

julia> nb_available(s)
0
(after 5 seconds or so...)
julia> nb_available(s)
0

julia> t=read(s,10)
10-element Array{UInt8,1}:
 0x32
 0x32
 0x30
 0x20
 0x73
 0x6d
 0x74
 0x70
 0x31
 0x34
(HOW, WHY???? nb_available==0, but read returns me 10 bytes?!)

... (read was repeated many times...)
julia> t=read(s,10)
^CERROR: InterruptException:
Stacktrace:
 [1] process_events at ./libuv.jl:82 [inlined]
 [2] wait() at ./event.jl:216
 [3] wait(::Condition) at ./event.jl:27
 [4] wait_readnb(::TCPSocket, ::Int64) at ./stream.jl:296
 [5] readbytes!(::TCPSocket, ::Array{UInt8,1}, ::Int64) at ./stream.jl:714
 [6] read(::TCPSocket, ::Int64) at ./io.jl:529
```

I dont want to use @async for the simplest case described above.

Who knows, how to read from TCP socket in non-blocking mode, when i can determine some way, whether read buffer contain any data or no and/or whether next read issued by tcp client will block overall client process or no.

Is it possible in Julia without "green threads" usage?

Comment: I don't see any functionality enabling you to use `MSG_DONTWAIT` or `MSG_PEEK` flags with `recv` etc, if that's what you mean. Alas, `@async` seems to be the way to go to achieve this. (happy to be corrected if I'm wrong though)

Comment: Not 100% "green threads", but as a workaround, I have noticed that doing `@async eof(socket)` just before `nb_available` seems to update its count (also `socket.buffer.size`), making it available for use (e.g. to check if the next instruction will block). Also, if you want to play with the socket's buffer without 'spending' it, so that you can 'peek' into the incoming messages without consuming them, you can turn `socket.buffer.seekable` to true and read / seek straight into `socket.buffer`. Remember to turn it back to `false` after you're done, so you can read straight from the socket again.

Comment: I'm assuming these are either bugs or necessary socket evils, so I'm not pretending this is solid advice. But it seems to work for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no-one's provided an "official" solution yet, here's the workaround I mentioned above.

**Functions:**

```julia
# Causes stagnant 'nb' count to be updated.
# Note asynchronous nature; this means refresh may not yet have occurred 
# when function has exited. 
function refreshBufsize(s)
  @async eof(s);
  return nothing;
end;
```

```julia
# Check if socket is blocked (refresh bytecount first)
# Note, since refresh is asynchronous, may misreport 'blockage' until
# 'refresh' operation is actually finished; however, if socket is actually
# unblocked, subsequent calls of this function will eventually properly
# report socket is not blocked, and in general, misreporting blockage once 
# or twice when socket is actually free is probably acceptable (rather 
# than other way round).
function isblocked(s)
  refreshBufsize(s)
  return nb_available(s) == 0;
end;
```

```julia
# Peek contents of socket without consuming stream
function peek(s, nb)
  refreshBufsize(s)
  s.buffer.seekable = true;
  Out = read(s.buffer, nb);
  seekstart(s.buffer);
  s.buffer.seekable = false
  return Out
end;
```

**Example:** (console outputs denoted as "#>" comments, for copy-pastable code)

```julia
server = listen(9001); 
sOut   = connect(9001); 
sIn    = accept(server);

nb_available(sIn)       
#> 0
isblocked(sIn)          
#> true
refreshBufsize(sIn); # we expect no change, as we haven't written anything yet
isblocked(sIn)          
#> true
write(sOut, "Greetinks and salutations!\n")  
#> 27
write(sOut, "We would be honoured if you would join us.\n") 
#> 43
refreshBufsize(sIn);
isblocked(sIn) # note: may say true at first (until refresh properly finished)
#> false
nb_available(sIn) 
#> 27
String( peek( sIn, 10)) # peek socket contents without consuming
#> "Greetinks "
String( read( sIn, nb_available( sIn))) # read (consume) as normal
#> "Greetinks and salutations!\n"
nb_available(sIn) # note 0 even though second buffer awaiting. needs refresh!
#> 0
isblocked(sIn) # note: called "refresh" under the hood 
               # (but keep async in mind, i.e. might say 'true' at first!)
#> false
nb_available(sIn)
#> 43
String( read( sIn, nb_available( sIn)))
#> "We would be honoured if you would join us.\n"
isblocked(sIn)
#> true
```

**EDIT:** for comparison, a more typical "asynchronous" socket session (which typically *relies* on such "blocking" behaviour) would probably look something like this:

```julia
server = listen(9002);
sOut   = connect(9002);
sIn    = accept(server);

TaskRef = @async try 
  while true
    In = String(readavailable(sIn));
    if !isempty(In); println("Received from server: $In"); else; break; end
  end
  println("Connection closed normally");
catch E
  println("Connection closed (with status $E)");
end;

write(sOut, "Stop repeating everything I say!\n");
#> Received from server: Stop repeating everything I say!

close(sIn)
#> Connection closed normally
```

Comment: Tasos, thank you for excellent answer! I understand what you mean, but for now i cant imagine, how to implement some generic library code for async reading and writing: i have to wait for isblocked(sIn) == false and call some callback to read some data from socket, but it leads to (presumable to be short) polling like while `isblocked(sIn) ;; end` :( How to avoid it?
Thanks again!

Comment: @drvtiny hahah, well, the whole point of my answer above was to provide a "single-thread" polling-based solution, because you said you wanted to avoid doing it asynchronously! Otherwise, yes, I agree, the best way to do this is indeed asynchronously! I can update my answer with a typical asynchronous approach to reading from a socket if you'd like?

Comment: Thank you very much again, Tasos!!