# Weird behaviour when sending and receiving through sockets in the same REPL session

Tags: sockets, julia

My question relates to the last part (i.e. the "edit" bit) on [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44985956/4183191), which involves a simple demonstration for receiving data asynchronously through a socket; as it is a toy example, the 'sending' socket is created within the same REPL session.

If I close the input stream `sIn`, or if I test with a proper external output stream (i.e. say I do a netcat session as opposed to `sOut = connect(9002)` from the same REPL session that I'm listening in) and then terminate that normally, everything works as expected.

But if instead of `close(sIn)` I do `close(sOut)`, the line `"Connection closed normally"` never gets executed, and I can't figure out why .... Any ideas?

Here's a copy of my terminal session demonstrating the weird behaviour:

```julia
julia> server = listen(9002);

julia> sOut   = connect(9002);

julia> sIn    = accept(server);

julia> TaskRef = @async try 
         while true
           In = String(readavailable(sIn));
           if !isempty(In); println("Received from server: $In"); else; break; end
         end
         println("Connection closed normally");
       catch E
         println("Connection closed (with status $E)");
       end;

julia> write(sOut, "Stop repeating everything I say!\n");
Received from server: Stop repeating everything I say!


julia> close(sOut);

julia> 
julia> istaskdone(TaskRef)
true

julia>
```

<sub>PS. This is on Julia version 0.7.0-DEV.874 / Linux Mint 64bit</sub>