# Check if data on a tcpsocket

Tags: julia

How can I check if there is data on a Base.TCPSocket, without blocking until there is data.

Something like [select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) where both values of the timeout-struct are set to 0.

Thanks to sbromberger who pointed me towards [nb_available](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/io-network/#Base.nb_available) which on paper does exactly what I want.

> Returns the number of bytes available for reading before a read from this stream or buffer will block.

Sadly this is not useful. Example:

[image]

On the left side it should say 8 bytes not 0.

Comment: Does `nb_available` do what you need?

Comment: @sbromberger I did not know this function exist. I just tried it and it seems to be inconsistent. I did a simple/client example and sometimes it correctly wrote that some bytes are available, sometimes it says 0 despite there being something on the buffer.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44969556/4183191

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on @tasos-papastylianou's linked solution, it appears that `@async eof(c)` on the server will cause `nb_available` to update. Note that it will provide the correct value at that point in time, and subsequent writes will not update `nb_available` without a `read`. Here's an example (assumes connection has been established already):

```
client> write(c, 12.5)

server> nb_available(c)
0

server> @async eof(c)
Task (done) @0x0000000123b7f850

server> nb_available(c)
8

client> write(c, 12.5)

client> write(c, 22.5)

server> nb_available(c)
8

server> @async eof(c)
Task (done) @0x0000000123b7c010

server> nb_available(c)
8

server> read(c,8)
8-element Array{UInt8,1}:
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x80
 0x36
 0x40

server> nb_available(c)
0

server> @async eof(c)
Task (done) @0x0000000123b7c010

server> nb_available(c)
16
```

Comment: Worth clarifying, there's nothing special about `eof`; any operation that inspects data on the stream somehow will case such an update to the reported buffer size. This is more likely to be a subtle julia bug rather than expected behaviour. There also seems to be bugs relating to accessing a socket as input and output from within the same session, as opposed to connecting via separate sessions.

Comment: I find that response in the julia-issues thread you linked to woefully inadequate and unsatisfying ... but oh well. :p

Comment: Tasos - jump in and comment!

Comment: ahahah  ... (sigh) fine, I'll give my 2¢ ... but this has all the hallmarks of the kind of discussion that could easily turn into a flamewar pedantfest ... just like the linked 'documentation' issue seems to have :p